# Sequelize - Model.create is not a function / Model.build is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating an app with Node.js, Sequelize, Mysql, Express. I'm very new to this, sorry if this question is stupid.

I have two models with a one to many relation : User and Token (a user has multiple tokens, a token has one user).

Here are the files :

models/user.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const Token = require('./token')
const db = require('../db/sequelize'),
      sequelize = db.sequelize,
      jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

// Model for a user (player)

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    // All the columns
})
    
User.gAuth = async function(user) {
    const token = jwt.sign({id: user.id.toString() },
        'password',
        {
            expiresIn: '7 days'
        })

    console.log(token)
    console.log(Token)

    const newToken = Token.create({
        token,
        user: this.id
    })

    console.log(newToken)

    await newToken.save()

    return token

}

module.exports = User
```

It's on "const newToken = Token.create({...})" that I have my error. It says : "Token.create is not a function". I tried with build, I had : "TypeError: Token.build is not a function".

models/token.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db/sequelize'),
    sequelize = db.sequelize
const User = require('./user')

const Token = sequelize.define('Token', {
    // All the columns
})

User.hasMany(Token, {
    as: 'tokens'
})

Token.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'UserId',
    as: 'user'
})

module.exports = Token
```

Can you please help me understands what I'm doing wrong ? All the answers I've found were about bad export of the Model, but I don't see my error.

Thank you !

EDIT :

When I console.log(sequelize.models) in models/token.js it returns : { User: User, Token: Token }

However ! When I console.log(sequelize.models) in models/user.js it retuns : { User: User }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY ! I found the thing I was doing wrong : structuring my files.

My function gAuth shouldn't have been on models/user.js but on models/token.js. Leaving it on user.js caused a **circular dependency** which was causing the bug.

I've removed gAuth from user.js, moved it to token.js and removed the require('./token') from user.js

I hope this can help some people with the same problem !

Thanks a lot to @about14sheep for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db/sequelize'),
      sequelize = db.sequelize,
      jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const Token = require('./token')(sequelize, Sequelize)
```

Edit:

As per the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) instead of importing Token directly try grabbing the token off the sequelize instance like so:

```
const db = require('../db/sequelize'),
   sequelize = db.sequelize,
   jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const token = sequelize.models.Token
```

Comment: It crashes the app with the following error : TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Comment: one thing you can do is console.log(Token) and tell me what it says. If it is an object then you can just use const {Token} = require('./token')

Comment: When I console.log(Token) it gives me this : "{}". I tried "const {Token}" but now when I try / catch Token.create this error shows up : " Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"

Comment: after reviewing the docs i have updated my answer

Comment: It's sadly not working : token is now undefined.

Comment: what version of sequelize are you using?

Comment: The 6.7.0, the latest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238253/discussion-between-austin-burger-and-joshua-fleuri).